# My app restarts sometimes

Tags: android

I have very strange behaviour of app.
For no visible reasons it can restart by itself (happens not too often, but happens)

Found that strange part in logs

```
11-14 08:38:09.029 3730-3730/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-14 08:38:09.029 3730-3730/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=-198.0, y[0]=36.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=402013472, downTime=402013463, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
11-14 08:38:09.029 3730-3730/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-14 08:39:42.126 26680-26739/? E/ModuleProvider: Unhandled query from com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals: content://com.google.android.gms.chimera/api/
11-14 08:39:42.127 3730-3730/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals I/ChimeraModuleLdr: Module config changed, forcing restart due to module 
11-14 08:39:42.127 3730-3730/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3730 SIG: 9
11-14 08:39:42.190 629-742/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '2f36e7dc com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals.Activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-14 08:39:42.190 629-742/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '2f36e7dc com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals.Activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-14 08:39:42.190 629-1222/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{37061ed4 u0 com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals.Activities.CoinInfoActivity}
11-14 08:39:42.195 629-1356/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2f36e7dc u0 com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals.Activities.MainActivity}
11-14 08:39:42.195 629-1356/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '2f36e7dc com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals.Activities.MainActivity (server)'
11-14 08:39:42.204 629-1481/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals (pid 3730) has died
11-14 08:39:42.204 629-1481/? W/ActivityManager: App Op not allow to restart app com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/10179
11-14 08:39:42.207 629-1481/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{3c9aa828 u0 com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/.Activities.CoinInfoActivity t1346}: app died, no saved state
11-14 08:39:42.231 629-1481/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals for activity com.cryptorulezz.cryptosignals/.Activities.MainActivity: pid=4222 uid=10179 gids={50179, 9997, 3003} abi=x86
```

When it restarts - all fragments are not attached to activity and I need to close app.
Any ideas?

Or just how to fully restart app in that case?
Like total restart with all setups

Comment: Related: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869289/consumer-closed-input-channel-or-an-error-occurred-events-0x8) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675610/consumer-closed-input-channel-or-an-error-occurred-events-0x8)

Comment: Probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865465/my-app-restarted-itself-log-shows-chimeramoduleldr-module-config-changed-forc/47347443#47347443

Comment: Hi, is you found the solution for the above mentioned challenge??